# Jira - Greenhopper KanBan - custom done action (move to new board - change status)

Tags: workflow, jira, jira-agile, jira-ondemand

We use jira with the Greenhopper plugin.

I am trying to find a way to chain workflows.

So lets say that we have a development workflow that goes

```
backlog -> queued -> development -> testing -> signoff -> done
```

Simple enough, but I want to create a planning workflow that could lead into this, for example it might be:

```
Feature request -> Priority -> Specification -> Signoff -> Done
```

Simple enough in its own right, but I want an item that is dropped in done (or released from done) to jump into the backlog column of the development workflow.

So I am looking for a way of controlling the 'done' action, or using a state transition to move a task to a new project/board (and sub tasks if exist) and change the status.

I am aware that I could use one long workflow and different boards and I can hide columns but I would like to be able to chain several possibly non related workflows.

I appreciate any clues.

---

EDIT  -  I am using the hosted Jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot get the result I needed.  You can almost get the effect I want by using one long workflow that uses a unique status for each state.  You can setup boards to group, or not display certain statuses.  So by using multiple boards on the same workflow,  and some manual moving of issues/ tasks this sort of works as required.  But the lack of automation is a kick.